# Nested Transactions in Django 1.4

Tags: python, mysql, django, transactions

A function A() is enabled for manual transaction. It has DB transactions and rolls back in case of any error. This function calls another function which is not enabled for manual transactions but has db transactions too raises an error in case of an exception . Will rollback in the parent function rollback db edit statements in the called function in this case??

I am using Mysql

```
import sys
import os

from polls.models import Choice
from django.db import transaction


def s1():
    with transaction.commit_manually():
        try:
            print "First Fun"
            choice_obj = Choice.objects.create(
                choice_text="heyaa", votes='1', question_id='1')
            s2()
            transaction.commit()

        except:
            print "Roll Fun"
            transaction.commit()
            transaction.rollback()


def s2():

    try:
        print "Second Fun"
        choice_obj = Choice.objects.create(
            choice_text="abcaa", votes='1', question_id='1')
        print a

    except:
        raise
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be rolled back as well, though not if you commit it first in your `except` block and there is no database-related exception that prevents commits.

The very definition of a database transaction (atomic, consistent, isolated, durable) prevents that it can be nested. It is possible to emulate a sort of nested transaction using savepoints (which Django 1.6+ uses), though these are not true transactions. In any case, if the outer-most transaction is rolled back (i.e. the only true database-transaction), the whole transaction is rolled back.

Just a quick note:
    except:
        transaction.commit()

This is probably undesired behaviour on any exception, but this will raise another error if the exception is a database-related error that marks the transaction as broken. In that case, a rollback is required.